# Rearrange layout with flex

Tags: css, flexbox, responsive-design

I have following html.

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="b"></div>
    <div id="c"></div>
</div>
```

With css `flex`, I have the following layout in desktop mode:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+            +             +             +
+     A      +      B      +      C      +
+            +             +             +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I would like to rearrange divs so that in mobile mode it looks like:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                                        +
+                   B                    +
+                                        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+                   +                    +
+        A          +          C         +
+                   +                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Is it possible with flex trick?

Comment: This might help https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp CSS has a property `order` using which you can specify the order of a flexible item.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried it with order. But the other thing I need is what @Minal Chauhan gives: the `flex` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive this using `flex order`

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;  
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#a, #b,#c{
  flex: 0 0 33.33%;
  text-align:center;
  min-height: 100px;
}
#a{
  background: red;
}
#c {
  background: blue;
}

@media (max-width:767px){
  #a {
    order: 2;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
  #b {
    order: 1;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  }
  #c {
    order: 3;
    flex: 0 0 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="a">a</div>
    <div id="b">b</div>
    <div id="c">c</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! In addition to `order`, another key is `flex-wrap` with `flex`. Thanks!

Comment: @hyperbola if you want to get rid of extra CSS then you can definitely use below 2nd answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can surely do this layout using flexbox.

Below CSS might help you.

```css
#wrapper{
  display:-webkit-box;
  display:-ms-flexbox;
  display:flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap:wrap;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
#wrapper>div{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:15px;
  -webkit-box-flex:1;
  -ms-flex:1;flex:1;
  text-align:center;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  #wrapper>#b{
    min-width:100%;
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group:0;
    -ms-flex-order:-1;
    order:-1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="a">a</div>
    <div id="b">b</div>
    <div id="c">c</div>
</div>
```